# How to check for (any) IP address in Behat/Mink?

Tags: drupal, behat, mink

I'm using Behat/Mink to test a Drupal 8 site.

I have an input field with an IP address and I want to make sure that the IP address has been recorded.  I don't want to check for a specific IP address because it might change, so I just want to ensure the field has some value.

Based on the assumption the IP address will include a period, I tried this:

```
 Then the "#edit-field-ip-0-value" element should contain "."
```

But this fails with the error:

```
    The string "." was not found in the HTML of the element matching css "#edit-field-ip-0-value". (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementHtmlException)
```

However, the value of the field is:

```
172.19.0.1
```

So there is a period; I don't understand why "contains" doesn't see it.

I also tried checking like this:

```
 Then the "#edit-field-ip-0-value" element should contain "0"
```

But it fails with the same error (string not found in the HTML of the element).

**EDIT**

This is the HTML I am trying to target:

```
<input class="js-text-full text-full form-text" data-drupal-selector="edit-field-ip-0-value" type="text" id="edit-field-ip-0-value" name="field_ip[0][value]" value="172.19.0.1" size="60" maxlength="255" placeholder="">
```

Comment: You could try to implement a custom step and use regular expression to also check the validity of the ip.

Comment: Can you share the html of the section?

Comment: @lauda I added the HTML; see my edit to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I ended up using:

```
  /**
   * @Then the :element element should contain an IP address
   *
   * Checks that the element with the specified CSS contains IP address value.
   */
  public function assertElementContainsIpAddress($element) {
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    // Alternately, substitute with getText() for the label.
    $element_value = $page->find('css', "$element")->getValue();
    $valid_ip_address = filter_var($element_value, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
    if ($valid_ip_address === FALSE) {
      throw new Exception("Valid IP address not found in element $element, which had a value of $element_value.");
    }
  }
```